# Showing img not found 404

Tags: html, asp.net

In register identity server i did manage to do for user to upload photo and in my manage/account at cshtml my image is not showing even tho it is uploaded and is in the folder, i tried to load it static but it is showing 404 not found either way

I am trying to show the image at the angular component html, and in cshtml file at identity manage
I have in my program.cs
`app.UseStaticFiles();`

this is my service for the uploadingfile

```
public UnitOfWork(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }


    public async void UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
      long totalBytes = file.Length;
        string filename = file.FileName.Trim('"');
        filename = EnsureFileName(filename);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (FileStream output = File.Create(GetPathAndFileName(filename)))
        {
            using (Stream input = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                int readBytes;
                while((readBytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    totalBytes += readBytes;
                }
            }

        }

    }
    private string GetPathAndFileName(string filename)
    {
        string path = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\uploads\\";
        if(!Directory.Exists(path)) 
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        return path + filename;
    }

    private string EnsureFileName(string filename)
    {
        if(filename.Contains("\\"))
            filename = filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        return filename;
    }
}
```

Register form

```
            <label asp-for="Input.ImagePath"></label>
            <input type="file" name="file"  />
            <span asp-validation-for="Input.ImagePath" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>`
```

Register cs file

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile file, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await   _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                _unitOfWork.UploadImage(file);
            var user = CreateUser();
```

And this is how i try to show it
`

```
            <label asp-for="ImagePath"></label>
            <img src="/uploads/@Model.ImagePath" class="img">
        </div>`
```

I also tried static with `<img src="~/uploads/kiko.jpg" class="img" alt="My image" />` and all are showing 404 not found .

Note: the image is creating under wwwroot/upload/"imagename" and stores into database the name of the image
it is just not showing in any way on the webpage

Comment: Please fix the formatting issue of the code. Some parts of the code are plain text.